# How to fix this: TypeError: expect a list of futures, not Task

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm trying to start a bunch of subprocess using asyncio.create_subprocess_exec:

```py
procs = []
for i in range(5):
    proc = await asyncio.create_subprocess_exec(...)
    procs.append(proc.wait())
    # doesn't work with this line either:
    procs.append(asyncio.create_task(proc.wait()))

await asyncio.wait(*procs,..)
# doesn't work with await asyncio.as_completed either. asyncio.gather do work, but I'd like to add timeout limit and return back to my code as earlier as possible.
```

the exception is:
TypeError: expect a list of futures, not Task
against line 'await asyncio.wait(*procs,..)
The verion of Python is 3.8.

Despite of be warned not to create future by myself in the official document, if there's a way to convert *proc* into Future, I'd like to try.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message says, you need to provide a **list** of futures. Using the `*` operator you are unpacking the list and passing its members as individual positional parameters. The correct invocation would be:

```
await asyncio.wait(procs)
```

Your original code worked with `gather()` because `gather()` actually does expect awaitables as individual positional arguments.

Comment: Thanks! the answer is correct. After made the change as you suggested, the code works.